# MSSQL Server insert float with SQL Data Client in C#

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework-core, localization, internationalization

I wrote a dotnet core console application which should insert some prices into a SQL server. On my own database it works fine.

My client has his own database which uses German language settings (uses comma instead of a point as a decimal separator).

The problem is, when I make an insert statement via the Console Application, the decimal separator gets ignored. E.g.: when I insert 5.27 the value in the table is 527 but if I run the exact same insert statement in the SSMS query, it works fine.

Do you have an idea what I have to setup in my SQL Connection to get this working?

here is the code:

```cs
string connetionString = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder()
{
    DataSource = _server,
    InitialCatalog = _db,
    UserID = _user,
    Password = _password
}.ConnectionString;

var connection = new SqlConnection(connetionString);

string sql = "INSERT INTO [dbo].[Artikelliste] ([Artikelnummer] ,[allgEinkaufspreis] ,[allgVerkaufspreis]) VALUES(@param1,@param2,@param3)";
    
using SqlCommand cmd = new(sql, connection);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@param1", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = entry.StyleCode + "-" + entry.ColorCode + (auspragung > 1 ? "-" + entry.SizeCode : "");
cmd.Parameters.Add("@param2", SqlDbType.Float).Value = 5.27;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@param3", SqlDbType.Float).Value = 7.2;
    
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

I also tried it with ef core at the beginning, but I had the same problems.

Comment: What SQL data type is your column? `5.27` is a `double` literal and won't experience Culture issues.

Comment: Aside - `float` is rarely the right type to use for monetary values - consider `decimal/numeric`

Comment: I need to have float as a type because another application has to import this data afterwards and throws an error if the type is different.

Comment: How is the column defined in the database?

Comment: The column is defined as a float

Comment: According to [float and real (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/float-and-real-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15), _Floating point data is approximate;_. So unless this is for a school project, you should be using an [Exact Numeric](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-types-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) such as `decimal/numeric` - as someone else already mentioned. If there's an issue with another application, modify the other application, or contact the person who wrote it and have them modify it.